# Flash Builder 4.7 Import as3 files into project

Tags: import, flash-builder

I want to add a library into my project but FB gives me 'source directory is invalid' on import.

the package is like so.
src/de/flintfabrik/starling/

I go to import files and point the the src but FB refuses. I guess I can create the packages manually?

Comment: Are you adding a SWC or .AS files to your project?

Comment: .as files as stated in the title.

Comment: If you're adding .as files, why not just add them to the directory structure, refresh your project in Flash Builder and then you can simply use an import statement to utilize the class?

Comment: Just to clarify, what I mean by adding them to the directory structure is to use Finder or Explorer and simply add them to your project directory, then refresh the project in Flash Builder and they should just show up in the file list which means you can then simply use the import statement to utilize those .as files in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a crazy idea to just copy and paste the folders 'de' and into the project directory. That worked. The files were dependent on the folder system.